# How can I force all Microsoft Office apps to the top on start?

Tags: microsoft-office

Is there an easy way (i.e. group policy) to force *all* Microsoft Office apps (Word, Excel, PP, Outlook) to the top?  I'm looking for something like the "Always on Top" option from Windows Task Manager.

Edit:  Sorry, I should have explained.  We run a proprietary database application through RDS (terminal services) that does not start Explorer.  This application opens office apps for document editing.  After we moved the application from Server 2003 to 2008r2 the office apps began to start in the background.  Since the database app becomes unresponsive to the user when an office app is started and is permanently maximized it is a huge hassle for the user to get the Office apps to the front.   i.e. They have to CTRL-ALT-DEL, start task manager, start explorer, click the icon on the task bar, etc....  This is not at all desirable.

Comment: even if there would be a way, what would be the users' benefit of it? If you've only a few applications "always on top" that could be useful, but having a lot of them, especially those which you generally use full screen doesn't really seems handy. Please explain a bit broader why do you want to set this.

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained my situation.  I've added it to the question.

Comment: I'm not sure you can straight do it. However if your tool is Office based (e.g. Access) and uses VBA or .NET then you have access to the office object model and you can run [AppActivate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278643.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), I think that would be a solution for you.

Comment: Unfortunately the tool (ERP) is completely proprietary, including the database.